# Forcing Git to always overwrite certain files

Tags: git

I use a remote desktop to do a lot of the hard work of my computations, and use my laptop for editing and testing small bits of code. I have primarily been using python lately, and use Spyder quite often. The workflow is like this:

1. I make a change on my laptops editor to some code
2. I push that change to my Git
3. I remotely connect to my desktop (which is in my office)
4. I pull those changes onto my desktop
5. I run the code, which automatically saves data into directories
6. I add those directories to a commit, and push them to Git
7. I pull the new data to my laptop to generate images, check changes, etc.

The issue is that sometimes, the `__pycache__` folder doesn't get added to the push from either my laptop or my desktop, and then on the next cycle, I have to do an override to force a pull from my desktop to Git, or laptop to Git. I understand the need when its other code that should actually trigger a pull conflict, but not when its the `__pycache__` folder, as this is just annoying. Should I

a. Always directly add files to my commit, i.e. don't use `git add .`

or

b. Is there a way to force Git to always override a local directory with the new upload, without giving me an error, i.e. what I have been doing, but more quickly.

Comment: Would it make sense to .gitignore the pycache files?

Comment: Is there a way to do that on every git pull?

Comment: You permanently add a pattern matching the pycache folder and/or files to your .gitignore file and then you add/commit the .gitignore file. Then pulls should ignore the files matching those patterns.

Comment: Ahh of course. I should have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to use `git rm` (or `git rm --cached`) once, to remove the files from Git's index and hence from *future* commits, before the `.gitignore` listing will take effect. All the old commits that have the committed compiled files will continue to have the committed compiled files.